# Same sharthis buttons on every page

Tags: html, sharethis

I want to use 2 types of sharethis buttons with different counts. One count for the page that is currently shown, and one in the footer that counts every share for the whole site (only http://example.com, not the articles or something, so not every share).

Here is a short example of the code next to the article:

```
<span class="st_facebook_custom"><img src="images/icons/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></span>
```

And here is a short example of the code in the footer:

```
<div class="share"><span class="st_facebook_hcount"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two buttons that get two different counts by using the following

The problem is that when you pass in http://example.com it does not give you counts for the whole site, just for the home page...

This is exactly how the FB like and Twitter count buttons work, they are on a per page level, not at a site wide level..

-Manu